# Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch yet no Google Sheets have been open

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, urlfetch

I have a Google Sheets document which pulls data via an API from a data source. Now whenever I go to pull data I get the error "Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch": [image: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch]

The odd thing is when I check my API data source it says I have only called for data once. Therefore I do not understand where I am eating up my 20,000 data fetches?

In addition to this I have shared the document with another gmail account and again I get the same issue so I therefore believe this error has nothing to do with the 20,000 quota which people keep talking about.

Lastly, I can have my Google drive closed all day, no Google Doc, Sheets open and then the first time I open anything I immediately get this error. Adding to the fact I have no idea where these 20,000 calls are coming from. In the past the Google Sheets document has worked great its just started to stop working in the last couple months.

Any insight is hugely appreciated,
Seb

Comment: You should notice that quotas are for the account, not by script. Check if you have other documents consuming your quota

Comment: How many seconds between each fetch?  If it's less than 4.32 then add some sleep time to it.

Comment: Hey Bruno. Thanks for the message. In my testing I would close down all Googledrive documents so that nothing was open. I leave it closed a day or so and then the moment I open it I get this message even though no documents have been open.

Comment: Hey Cooper I look up the line in the script which the error message is being generated from and as expected it is linked to:

 var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

How would I go about implenting a sleep function to my Import JSON? Sorry coding isn't my forte.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you please provide your code? Please make sure to sanitise it from anything sensitive first though!

Comment: Since adding the Utilities.Sleep() before the UrlFetchApp.Fetch(url) line everything seems to be working. Hopefully it continues. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Hey Rafa. How do I add my code as its the ImportJSON is larger than the 500 characters left in this comment?

Unfortunately the Utilities.Sleep() isn't working and I am still getting the error message.